# Get `LoggerInterface` instance in Laravel >=5.6 (replacement for `Log::getMonolog()`)?

Tags: laravel

I am using a 3rd party library that provides a constructor which expects an instance of `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`. The constructor in that code looks like:

```
public function __construct(
    $configuration = null,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger = null
)
{
```

In my Laravel 5.5 application I had written a service provider to set up that library for me, and I got access to a `LoggerInterface` for it by using Laravel's `Log::getMonolog()`:

```
$connection_manager = ConnectionManager::factory(
    config('the_lib_config'),
    \Log::getMonolog()
);
```

With the changes to logging that took place in Laravel 5.6, however, the method `getMonolog` has gone away. I understand why this method isn't there now, but I'm wondering what the prescribed method is to get what this class needs so that it can log in context of the Laravel app (with all the new Laravel logging goodness).

Comment: https://github.com/freshbitsweb/slack-error-notifier/issues/7#issuecomment-442318394

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Google-Fu got stronger throughout the day, and I found the answer I was looking for in a response by @ermyril at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/getting-laravels-logger-instance?reply=530098

The answer is:

```
\Log::getLogger();
```